# Inserting Values in 3D Map in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am new to map in C++ and have one 3D map, like this

```
map<int,map<const char*,const char*>>Map3D;
```

I want to insert values in such a way that int value increments when both const char* values are more than 50. I am keeping a track of const char* value. Can anyone tell me how i can insert value in this map. I am doing something like this

```
Map3D.insert(pair<int,map<const char* ,const char*>(count,pair<const char*,const char*>(TempA,TempB)));
```

But it's not working.

**EDIT**

```
std::map<int,map<const char*,const char*>>::iterator it= Map3D.begin();
std::map<const char*, const char*>::iterator sub_it = subMap.begin();
```

Comment: Why are you using a `map<const char*, const char*>`? That will not sort the elements lexicographically. Lookup will be difficult too. Consider using a `map<string, string>` instead.

Comment: @DDrmmr, I am filling this map with a output from a API function and that function return `const char*`

Comment: And how do you know that that function always returns the same pointer for the same string value? Or different pointers for different string values for that matter?

Comment: there is one iterator in the function, which iterates through the object returned by the function. I am tracking the iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a missing `>`, and you can't recursively insert `std::pair` into inner maps, you'll have to either create a new map or use an existing one

```
  map<int,map<const char*,const char*>> Map3D;
  map<const char*,const char*> subMap;

  const char hello[] = "hello";
  const char world[] = "world";

  subMap.insert(std::pair<const char*,const char*>(hello, world));
  Map3D.insert(std::pair<int,map<const char*,const char*>>(22, subMap));
```

---

Edit: to read back elements take a look at [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5b%5d/)

```
  map<const char*,const char*> subMapCopy = Map3D[22];
  cout << subMapCopy[hello]; // world
```

Edit II: with iterators: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/begin/

```
 std::map<int,map<const char*,const char*>>::iterator it= Map3D.begin();
 std::map<const char*, const char*>::iterator sub_it = subMap.begin();
 cout << it->second[sub_it->first]; // world
```

Comment: Sir, I want to access the elements by iterator method. I made two iterators and edited the question. If not too pressing for you, can you please help with them. Thanks

Comment: @Hamid Edited II, but this is getting off-topic, make another question if you add other data

Comment: Please have a look at it..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24366401/inserting-and-reading-values-from-3d-map